# Doea a 2004 buick century have a timing belt?

Tags: timing-belt, buick, century

Does a 2003 Buick century have a timing belt?

Comment: Welcome to the site. First, is it a 2003 or 2004? It says both in the title/question.

Answer (score 2):

The first Google result says it all: https://repairpal.com/when-do-i-change-timing-belt-404

This car has a timing chain. No timing belt worries, then. Also, no chain worries according to the link. Some cars with timing chains have a chain system that isn't good for the entire life of the car, but apparently your car doesn't have such a poor timing chain system.

Comment: The chain on those 3.4 and 3.8 engines will more than likely outlast the life of the car.

Comment: This is also apparently true for the 2003.

Comment: FWIW wikipedia says its a 3.1L.   In case others come across this, where you need to worry about GM timing *chains* is on overhead cam motors (which he sure doesn't have in the Century)